# Generate reports in SP 2013 Online without using Excel or SSRS?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, reports

We are working with a SP 2013 Online client that needs to have reports generated but they do not have Excel 2013 installed.  Is there a way to still generate reports?  I would like to use Power Pivot but since this is a 2013 Online version, don't I need to have Excel 2013 installed as well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What "reports" means in your context? E.g. List based tabular views, should it be flexible, available for the end-user to customize, etc.  - have you considered building via Client Side Rendering your own Javascript based views

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2013 is only required to build the reports and publish them.  You are not required to have it for viewing the published reports (they are rendered entirely online).

You can still utilize Excel services without PowerPivot to display data as well.  These can be created in Excel 2010.  If you need to implement some type of sorting / filtering, then you can do that thru a combination of connected web parts, filter web parts, and custom views.

Alternatives are client side frameworks like Google charts for displaying graphs or JQuery plugins for creating Pivot Tables.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately the client does wish to build and publish these reports.  Is there any way to get around this?